# Fill DataFrame based on value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following python pandas dataframe:

| province | district |
| --- | --- |
| Total | example |
| NaN | other |
| Other | NaN |
| NaN | example |
| Result | example |
| NaN | example |

If the province column is NaN and the value for that row is 'example', I want to fill the province gap with 'example'. The rest of the rows stay as they are.

DataFrame result:

| province | district |
| --- | --- |
| Total | example |
| NaN | other |
| Other | NaN |
| example | example |
| Result | example |
| example | example |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.fillna()` conditionally with `np.where`:

```
df["province"] = np.where(
    df["district"] == "example", 
    df["province"].fillna(value="example"), 
    df["province"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `loc` to find the rows with `NaN` in your province column and 'example' in your district column and update the values in your province column to be 'example':

```
df.loc[(df.province.isnull()) & (df.district.eq('example')),'province'] = 'example'
```

prints:

```
  province district
0    Total  example
1      NaN    other
2    Other      NaN
3  example  example
4   Result  example
5  example  example
```